# Add a PHP variable in SQL (function)-statement

Tags: php, function

```
    function GetFieldFromStelling($Field, $ID, $mysqli) {
        $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ? FROM stemmen WHERE ID = ?");
        $query->bind_param("si", $Field, $ID);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($results);
        $query->fetch();            
        return $results;
    }
```

Hi everyone,

I am trying to add a variable to the select statement but it does not work, does anyone have any input?

The output of the function is the string I put in the $Field part.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use parameters for column (and table) names

Comment: Not an exact match, but the mechanics and reasoning are the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter